# AWK variables and functions syntax

Tags: function, variables, awk, substring, lowercase

I would like to remove "_" and ":" in the texts and then convert the texts into lowercase in AWK but couldn't get it working. Here's a simple `data.txt` file:

```
Count_Part:AA,1,2,3,4,5
Name_Date:BB,4,5,6,7,8
```

and my script `process.awk`:

```
BEGIN{
  FS=",";
}
{
        print("raw -->", $1);
        replaced=$gsub(/_|:/, "", $1);
        print("replacement -->", $replaced);
        lowered=$tolower($replaced);
        print("to lowercase -->", $lowered);
        print("\n");
}
```

but what I get from `cat data.txt | awk -f process.awk` is this, which is not  what I expected:

```
raw --> Count_Part:AA
replacement --> CountPartAA
to lowercase --> CountPartAA 1 2 3 4 5


raw --> Name_Date:BB
replacement --> 6
to lowercase -->
```

I am wondering 1) why the `CountPartAA` is not printed as `countpartaa`, and 2) why the 2nd row of the data.txt did not have the similar output as the 1st row did.

I suspect it's due to the variable assignment and function return syntax but I could not make it work. My expected output is like this:

```
raw --> Count_Part:AA
replacement --> CountPartAA
to lowercase --> countpartaa


raw --> Name_Date:BB
replacement --> NameDateBB
to lowercase --> namedatebb
```

Please kindly help. Thanks!

Comment: Think of `$` as an _operator_ that retrieves the value of the given field: `$1` => value of field 1; `$(NF - 1)` => value of 2nd last field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, need to remove sigills `$` on functions and variables apart $1 :

```
BEGIN{
  FS=",";
}
{
        print("raw -->", $1);
        gsub(/_|:/, "", $1);     # return integer and modify $1 directly 
        replaced=$1
        print("replacement -->", replaced);
        lowered=tolower(replaced);
        print("to lowercase -->", lowered);
        print("\n");
}
```

### output

```
raw --> Count_Part:AA
replacement --> CountPartAA
to lowercase --> countpartaa


raw --> Name_Date:BB
replacement --> NameDateBB
to lowercase --> namedateb
```

Answer (score 2):

you mean like this ?

```
{m,n,g}awk '$!NF=tolower($!(NF=NF))' FS='[_:]' OFS=
 
countpartaa,1,2,3,4,5
namedatebb,4,5,6,7,8
```

Comment: Nice, +1, but I don't get all the parts of the command. Especially `$!`. Could you explain a bit please ?

Comment: cool! but I have no idea why it works. Could you please explain a little? Thanks!

Comment: split it up into components :  $, for field ,  !, for logical negate or numerical invert, NF, for # fields.  if it's a blank row, NF=0, then !NF becomes 1, so that becomes $1 = tolower($1), but since it's blank row, the outcome of that is still "" empty string, so blank rows are skipped. if NF is positive, say NF=7,  left side is $ ( ! 7 ) becomes $0, right side, NF=NF performs same function as $1 = $1, it'll convert all spots with FS ( which i set to underscore "_" or colon " : " ) to OFS, which u can see i left open ( OFS= ), which is same as OFS="" (setting it empty string) ……..

Comment: ….. which means NF=NF performs the function of scrubbing out all underscores and colons. the result value of NF=NF is same as original NF, since i'm setting NF to the value of itself, so right side becomes tolower(  $ (  ! ( NF ) ) ) …. and continuing from above example, NF has value of 7, so right side becomes tolower ( $ ( ! ( 7 ) ) )  >>> tolower( $ ( ! 7 ) )  >>> tolower( $0 ) …..whole thing becomes a boolean evaluation for string value of  $0 = tolower( updated-$0 ). I've already set NF once, so as long as the output from tolower( ) isn't an empty string ""…...

Comment: ….. boolean eval yields TRUE, or 1 in awk parlance, which triggers the implicit default action block item of { print }. One extra point to keep in mind - FS here is underscore or colon, instead of the default " " - meaning leading edge and trailing edge spaces/tabs don't get scrubbed, all existing spaces and tabs preserved as is, while rows with ONLY spaces and tabs will actually get printed because it's not an empty string

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, you should not prefix function calls using `$` so do not:

```
replaced=$gsub(/_|:/, "", $1);
```

but rather

```
replaced=gsub(/_|:/, "", $1);
```

You are also misunderstanding how `gsub` works, from [GNU AWK User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

> `gsub(regexp, replacement [, target])`
>
> Search *target* for *all* of the longest, leftmost, *nonoverlapping* matching substrings it can find and replace them with *replacement*.(...)The `gsub()` function returns the number of substitutions made.(...)

Therefore you might disregard return value if you just need changes in string, e.g. if you need to remove digits from first column you might just do

```
awk '{gsub(/[0-9]/, "", $1);print}' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @Daweo for pointing the issues in my codes. The `{m,n,g}awk '$!NF=tolower($!(NF=NF))' FS='[_:]' OFS=` works but when I tried to add `tolower`, like this: ` awk '{tolower(gsub(/_|:/, "", $1)); print}' data.txt`, the tolower() part is not working. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: `gsub` does *return* number of changes done, why you try to apply `tolower` to number?